# How would I produce an integer from a float in the sense of removing the decimal point, despite floating-point precision errors?

Tags: c, floating-point

In C, how can I produce, for example 314159 from 3.14159 or 11 from 1.1 floats? I may not use `#include` at all, and I am not allowed to use library functions. It must be completely cross platform, and fit in a single function.

I tried this:

```
while (Number-(int)Number) {
    Number *= 10;
}
```

and this:

```
Number *= 10e6;
```

and floating-point precision errors get in my way. How can I do this? How can I accurately transform all digits in a float into an integer?
In response to a comment, they are a `float` argument to a function:

```
char *FloatToString(char *Dest, float Number, register unsigned char Base) {
    if (Base < 2 || Base > 36 || !Dest) {
        return (char *)0;
    }
    char *const RDest = Dest;
    if (Number < 0) {
        Number = -Number;
        *Dest = '-';
        Dest++;
    }
    register unsigned char WholeDigits = 1;
    for (register unsigned int T = (int)Number/Base; T; T /= Base) {
        WholeDigits++;
    }
    Dest[WholeDigits] = '.';
    // I need to now effectively "delete" the decimal point to further process it. Don't answer how to convert a float to a string, answer the title.
    return RDest;
}
```

Comment: Do you need to handle negative numbers? Are there always five digits after the decimal?

Comment: @user3386109 I don't know how many digits can be after a float, so 5 is just my guess for my example

Comment: (a) No binary floating-point format represents the number 3.14159. The closest the common format for `double` comes is 3.14158999999999988261834005243144929409027099609375. So, if the user gives you that number, will you give the digits of that or the digits of 3.14159? How would you know what the user meant? (b) 3.25000 and 3.25 are the same number. Do you want to produce 25000 or 25? Why one and not the other? (c) For 3.0625, you could get 625, but how will you know it needs to be “0625”?

Comment: Your second paragraph indicates this is an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem): You want to format a floating-point number in decimal (X), and you have decided to make the fractional part into a decimal integer (Y). Unfortunately, the Y is not a good way to go about accomplishing X.

Comment: If you're trying to reproduce the functionality of `printf`, you should look at an existing implementation, e.g. take a look at the glibc source.

Comment: Converting binary floating-point to decimal is actually a somewhat hard problem, at least to do efficiently. It can actually be done “simply” using grade-school arithmetic for long division, at the expense of wasting a bunch of memory. But, if you are doing a school assignment, that might be a fine way to go. What is the actual assignment?

Comment: "how would I produce integer 14159 from float 3.14159?" is a problem because typical `float` cannot have the value of 3.14159.  it could have a value near it like 3.141590118408203125 as all finite `float` have a significand that is [dyadic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadic_rational), not decimal. So without post explaining why 5 places rather than 18 this question lacks a clear goal.

Comment: "I have already written an int to string function" --> I suspect that fails for large values and edge cases.  Posting that would help see where you have been and where this is going.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Given "I am not allowed to use library functions", I strongly suspect this is not an XY problem but a homework problem.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: Yes, as one of my comments notes, but the assignment is likely to convert a floating-point number to decimal without using `printf` *et al*, not to convert the fraction part of a floating-point number to an integer as the question requests.

Comment: What's the result of removing the decimal point from `0.01` (`1` or `001` [not an int]) and `10^30` (`1` or something too big to be an int)?

Comment: @user3386109 Where is the actual glibc implementation?

Comment: @0x10 google "glibc source code github"

Comment: @AndrewHenle It's still XY when their description is not their instructor's description.

Comment: What is the exact form of the inputs & outputs & how are they input & output? What is your exact assignment? You are not clearly saying what the task is. "for example 314159 from 3.14159 or 11 from 1.1 floats" These are examples of what, exactly? Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean.

Comment: @philipxy I am saying, givin the float 312.198471983, how can I produce an integer 312198471983? For example. How can I effectively "remove" the decimal point?

Comment: That is too vague. And: Please clarify via edits, not comments. What is your deliverable? A function with what arguments with what types that returns or outputs what? A main() that expects what input exactly & outputs what function of inputs in what format via what functionality? Etc. Say enough that someone could go away & come back with a solution & a user knows how to use it. PS Putting words in scare quotes does not make clear the idiosyncratic specific meaning that you didn't write out. PS Again: Quote your assignment exactly. PS You have been told, *there is no C float* "312.198471983".

Answer (score 1):

The essential problem you have is that floating point numbers can't represent your example numbers, so your input is always going to be slightly different.  So if you *accurately* produce output, it will be different from what you expect as the input numbers are different from what you think they are.

If you don't have to worry about very large numbers, you can do this most easily by converting to a long:

```
v = v - (long)v;   // remove the integer part
int frac = (int)(v * 100000);
```

will give you the 5 digits after the decimal point.  The problem with this is that it give undefined behavior if the initial value is too large to be converted to a long.  You might also want to be rounding differently (converting to int truncates towards zero) -- if you want the closest value rather than the leading 5 digits of the fraction, you can use `(int)(v * 100000 + (v > 0 ? 0.5 : -0.5))`

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: not true, though it does leave it as a negative number -- eg if `v` is `-15.356`, `v-(long)v` is `-0.356`

Comment: There are floating-point functions for rounding/truncating to integer, like `trunc`.

Comment: Given `double v = .12507;`, this code produces 12506 (in a C implementation where `double` is IEEE-754 binary64).

Comment: Or, for `float` rather than `double`, `float v = .12504;` produces 12503 (in a C implementation where `float` is IEEE-754 binary32).

Comment: @EricPostpischil: That's because a float can't exactly represent those numbers -- when you say `float v = .12504` you're actually getting `0.125039994716644287109375`, so 12503 is the correct answer.  If you want the closest integer (rather than the first five digits), you need to round rather than truncating.

Comment: I know the reason the result is wrong. But having a reason it is wrong does not fix the problem that it does not provide the result OP seeks.

Comment: Also, if the reasoning is that this code produces 12504 given `float v = .12504` is because `v` then has the value .125039994716644287109375, so the code truncates the remaining digits, then we can look at the behavior given `float v = .12503`, for which `v` has the value 0.12502999603748321533203125, but the routine produces 12503, not 12502. So there is no consistent specification for what this code does. Sometimes it rounds and sometimes it truncates?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(void) {
    double t = 0.12;
    unsigned long x = 0;

    t = (t<0)? -t : t;  // To handle negative numbers.
    for(t = t-(int)t; x < ULONG_MAX/10; t = 10*t-(int)(10*t))
    {
        x = 10*x+(int)(10*t);
    }

    printf("%lu\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

### Output:

```
11999999999999999644
```

Comment: Changing `double t = 3.1415926;` to `double t = .12;` results in output “8662109375” (in a C implementation where `double` is IEEE-754 binary64 and `unsigned long` is 64 bits).

Comment: @EricPostpischil:  Fair point, but easily fixed.  I edited my answer to address that.

Comment: Given `t = .12`, the actual value of t is 0.11999999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875. If we were going to produce 21 digits of it, we should have 119999999999999995559, not 11999999999999999644.

Comment: That's an interesting quibble.  But I think I've given the most complete, most accurate answer (by a LONG ways) on this question.   The other answers don't even come close.

Answer (score 0):

New version :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    double x;
    int i;
    char s[10];
    x = 9999.12504;
    x = (x-(int)x);
    sprintf(s,"%0.5g\n",x);
    sscanf((s+2),"%d",&i);


    printf("%d",i);
    return 0;
}
```

Old version

```
#include <stdio.h>

    int main()
    {
        float x;
        int i;
        x = -3.14159;
        x = (x-(int)x);
        if (x>=0)
            i = 100000*x;
        else
            i = -100000*x;

        printf("%d",i);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: For `x = .12504;`, this prints “12503”.

Comment: Ok, i did a new version with sscanf and sprintf

Comment: Per the question:  "I am not allowed to use library functions"

Answer (score -2):

I feel like you should use modulo to get the decimal portion, convert it to a string, count the number of characters, and use that to multiply your remainder before casting it to an int.

Comment: modulo only works on integers in C -- applying `%` to float arguments is UB

Comment: Applying % to floats for me is just a straight out compiler error

Comment: If you could convert the fraction portion to a string (were allowed by the conditions of the problem assignment), you would be done: Printing the floating-point number as decimal is the goal. Counting the digits and using that to multiply to get the digits as an integer would be a waste.

Comment: @ChrisDodd: This answer suggested using modulo, not using the `%` operator. There us a modulo/remainder operation for floating-point. (And, the `fmod` result is always exact; there is never any rounding.)

Comment: @EricPostpischil: but fmod is a library function, which the OP says he can't use...